# How can I convert a string to "two" integers in Lua?

Tags: string, lua, numbers

How can I convert a string to "two" integers in Lua?

I have a string like this:

```
string = "10 45"
```

I would like it to be converted to two numbers, `n1=10` and `n2=45.`

Comment: -1, this is very basic and is covered pretty extensively in the reference manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
s="10 45"
n1,n2=string.match(s,"(%d+)%s+(%d+)")
n1=tonumber(n1)
n2=tonumber(n2)
```

Comment: This assumes that the integers are positive.

Comment: To support negative integers: `'(%-?%d+)%s+(%-?%d+)'`. To support negative integers with arbitrary text between them (not just whitespace): `'(%-?%d+)[^%-0-9]+(%-?%d+)'`.

Comment: @Mud, you need to escape `-` as in `%-`.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. (I tested it and it worked the way it was, but better to be working because you're correct than because you got lucky.)

Answer (score 0):

You can split this string using split function like in example on page:
[Split in lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin)

and Lua provides automatic conversions between numbers and strings at run time so it's not a problem to write numbers to n1 and n2.

Comment: This can be a problem when you'd like to compare the string with a number. Then the string is not coerced.